# Accessing socks5 proxy network through Wi-Fi hotspot in android

Tags: networking, proxy, iptables

Please, for the purpose of comprehension, I will provide the details as much as possible; therefore, please be patient. I'll be very appreciated.

I have an android smartphone. I was using ProxyDroid to connect to a SOCKS5 proxy server, And then I turned on the hotspot on this android smartphone, and I used an iPhone to connect to the Wi-Fi hotspot, which was created by the android smartphone.

[**Solved**]The problem is my iPhone isn't able to access the Internet through the socks5 server. (But the Internet was working perfectly)

So, I am trying to find out why.
I am enclosing more details about what ProxyDroid did, and I took a glance into its source code:
[ProxyDroid source on github](https://github.com/madeye/proxydroid)
basically, after it calls redsocks, it also runs a few lines of iptables commands after the sock5 proxy is established(port 8124 is not being used, it's for HTTP proxy):

```
 $DIR/redsocks -p $DIR/redsocks.pid -c $DIR/redsocks.conf
 iptables -A INPUT -i ap+ -p tcp --dport 8123 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A INPUT -i ap+ -p tcp --dport 8124 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 8123 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 8124 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8123 -j DROP
 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8124 -j DROP
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ap+ -p tcp -d 192.168.43.1/24 -j RETURN
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ap+ -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to $proxy_port
```

and then, at the end:
(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is my socks5 server IP)

```
/system/bin/iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j RETURN
/system/bin/iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to 8123
```

I found a temporary solution; according to here [create-wifi-hotspot-access-point](http://abidmujtaba.blogspot.com/2016/07/ubuntu-create-wifi-hotspot-access-point.html), it mentions I have to do a few extra steps in order to make the hotspot forward all the traffic to redsocks(a socks5 proxy created by ProxyDroid):
(by the way, 192.168.43.0/24 is my hotspots' subnet, and 8123 is redsocks' local port)

```
iptables -F 
iptables -t nat -F 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.43.0/24 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8123
```

Finally, it worked! But another problem came up, the Internet speed of my iPhone became extremely slow, and I found out the DNS queries didn't go through the socks5 server. And because I executed iptables -F, which is above, it deleted the rules that are made by ProxyDroid, and my android smartphone wasn't able to access the socks5 proxy.

**[this one is solved]** I want my android smartphone and my iPhone to be able to access the internet through the socks5 server simultaneously.

I solved the problem that my android phone and iPhone can't access the internet at the same time. The reason is that ProxyDroid actually has already done it for me.
I have picked the exact commands that ProxyDroid has done to the hotspot(I put it below), letting hotspot traffic forward to socks5 proxy, and the reason why it didn't work on my case is because the interface of the hotspot has changed to "wlan1", so I changed "ap+" to "wlan1" for all of the four commands, it worked, I don't need to any extra iptables working. ***But the Internet speed on my iPhone still remains slow, I tried to browse either Google.com or Youtube.com, but it didn't go as fast as on my android smartphone.*** On the other hand, the ping speed and download speed are quite equivalent compared to the android smartphone.

```
 ***iptables -A INPUT -i ap+ -p tcp --dport 8123 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A INPUT -i ap+ -p tcp --dport 8124 -j ACCEPT 
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ap+ -p tcp -d 192.168.43.1/24 -j RETURN
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ap+ -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to $proxy_port***
```